# How to perform multiple autocomplete in textfields?

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, autocomplete, uitextfield

I have an array with some names. As I star typing i created a table and i display an autocompletion table containing possible data. Once i select that it appears in the textfield.
ACTUAL PROBLEM: what I'm trying to do is if after selecting the fist suggestion i start typing further and  insert a "," and start typing again i need the autocomplete to work for it too. so far i have managed to get it to work for only the initial text.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    _autocompleteTableView.hidden = NO;
    NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
    substring = [substring stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    [self searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:substring];
    return YES;
}
- (void)searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:(NSString *)substring {

        [_autocompleteFriends removeAllObjects];
        NSString *pattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".*\\b%@.*", [NSRegularExpression escapedPatternForString:substring]];
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self MATCHES[c] %@", pattern];
        _autocompleteFriends= [_arrFriendName filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate].mutableCopy;
        [_autocompleteTableView reloadData];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
     return _autocompleteFriends.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    static NSString *AutoCompleteRowIdentifier = @"AutoCompleteRowIdentifier";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:AutoCompleteRowIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [_autocompleteFriends objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;

}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    _txtName.text = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
    [_autocompleteTableView setHidden:YES];

}

@end
```

Comment: Maybe you could split the NSString into an Array separated by commas and take the last Object of it for autocompletion:  `[[searchString componentsSeparatedByString:@","] lastObject];`

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more. @3vangelos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could separate the string from the textfield by its components, so your method could look sth. like this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    _autocompleteTableView.hidden = NO;
    NSString *textFromTextfield = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
    NSString *substring = [[textFromTextfield componentsSeparatedByString:@","] lastObject];
    substring = [substring stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    [self searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:substring];
    return YES;
}
```

Hope this gets you on the right track!